# Weird artefacts with <feGaussianBlur/> on images in safari and mobile browsers

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters, gaussianblur

I am currently blurring images and using these as background whenever an image gets contained.
I am using the following svg filter with a filter spread out in two steps using `feGaussianBlur` and `feColorMatrix`. This renders perfectly in Chrome but in Safari and mobile browsers I see weird artefacts.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <filter
      id="blurry"
      width="150%"
      height="150%"
      x="-25%"
      y="-25%"
      colorInterpolationFilters="sRGB"
    >
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="45" />
      <feColorMatrix
        type="matrix"
        values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 10 0"
      />
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="45" />
      <feColorMatrix
        type="matrix"
        values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 10 0"
      />
      <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Then in my CSS I use:

```
-webkit-filter: url('#blurry');
        filter: url('#blurry');
```

Desired result (on desktop):

[image: Desired result]

Result I got:

[image]

It shows these weird gaps..

Some things I've noticed:

- Changing the filter size and position does not work
- On some images I don't see these artefacts
- Changing the filter `stdDeviation` does not work

Could it have something to do with the resolution of my images?

Comment: What is wrong with your image?  It's not clear without an example of what it is supposed to look like.  Can you post the original SVG - or a cutdown one if necessary - that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes will do @PaulLeBeau

Answer (score 1):

Those are big blurs - so Safari might be downscaling the filter resolution. Although it's deprecated and I think removed from Firefox and Chrome - you can try setting an explicit filterRes in your filter element because that's still supported in Safari.

(Also "colorInterpolationFilters" should be "color-interpolation-filters")

Comment: Thanks, will try that. I forgot to mention, I'm using React, so every attribute should be written in camel-case!

Comment: Adding filterRes to my filter does nothing unfortunately, and even if it did work, I guess I had to search for an alternative to downscale the filter..

Comment: try setting filterRes="500" and then 1000 and then 2000 - just to see what happens